# Problem with Sharepoint ContentTypeBinding and Lookup field

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, lookup, sitetemplate, lookupfield

I have a problem with ContentTypeBinding when creating a new site. I have custom site template definition where I have referenced Publishing Server Feature, so list Pages is automatically created on site. I need to bind custom content type to OOB Pages list. Do anybody know how to do that? My custom content type is deployed by feature on site collection scope.

Now I trying to do it in this way, but it's not working. In site template I referencing feature, which contains element with content type binding:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeId="GUIDOFCONTENTTYPE" ListUrl="Pages" />
</Elements>
```

I'm getting this error when I try to create new site:

SPContentTypeBindingElement.ElementActivated(). An error occurred binding content type     '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF390045BF70D1ABCA4A5BBF576B785EB3A37D' to list '/site/Pages' on web 'http://xxx/site'.  Exception '0x80070057owssvr.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000034256)
 at 0x000007FEE9954256 mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BF6D7)
 at 0x000007FEF61FF6D7 Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DAB02)
 at 0x000007FEEAD9AB02 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001A7B029)
 at 0x000007FEEE8BB029 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001BDCBB1)
 at 0x000007FEEEA1CBB1 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AB76AB)
 at 0x000007FEEE8F76AB Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AB7D2A)
 at 0x000007FEEE8F7D2A Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AB6E1F)
 at 0x000007FEEE8F6E1F Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001BFCB4F)
 at 0x000007FEEEA3CB4F Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001BFDF52)
 at 0x000007FEEEA3DF52 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000025D073E)
 at 0x000007FEEF41073E Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000025D0DEC)
 at 0x000007FEEF410DEC Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001F0BD0F)
 at 0x000007FEEED4BD0F Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001F0D8A6)
 at 0x000007FEEED4D8A6 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001D2B8EE)
 at 0x000007FEEEB6B8EE Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AD36D4)
 at 0x000007FEEE9136D4 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AD2F86)
 at 0x000007FEEE912F86 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000020D4DCD)
 at 0x000007FEEEF14DCD Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000022B8A80)
 at 0x000007FEEF0F8A80 Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001B006B6)
 at 0x000007FEEE9406B6 Microsoft.S'.

Have anybody some experience with that?

**UPDATE:**

I finded what causes my problem. It's lookup field in my content type. When I put this lookup out it works OK. But I still don't know how to resolve it.

Definition of my lookup:

```
<Field ID="{2FF1B484-6D70-449c-8E5C-904E4D5971E1}"
     Name="PageCategory"
     Group="Intranet Columns"
     Type="Lookup"
     DisplayName="PageCategory"
     List="Lists/Categories"
     ShowField="Title"
     PrependId="TRUE"/>
```

I know, that before this field is created list Categories must exists. So my Categories list is created in web-scope feature A and this lookup field, content type + lookup field and content type binding is in another feature B. I added dependency from B to A. Both features are referenced in onet.xml. Unfortunately I've got still the some problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue already. If somebody else is interested in the solution, it is here:
[Problem with Sharepoint ContentTypeBinding and Lookup field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/problem-with-sharepoint-contenttypebinding-and-lookup-field)